# How to Fix: Main function is Unreachable - Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to make a dead-simple bot according to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Jwd69MRYwg

The main function that is supposed to be called when a part of the screen changes color simply is not being run at all.

I've tried ending the program with

```
"main()"
```

and

```
"if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()"
```

respectively. Neither have allowed the code to run

```
def restart_game():
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(Coordinates.replayBtn)
```

```
def image_grab():
    box = (290, 465, 305, 487)
    image = image_grab_lib.grab(box)
    grey = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    a = array(grey.getcolors())
    print(a.sum())
    return a.sum()
```

```
def main():
    restart_game()
    print("blip")
    if image_grab() != 577:
        print("Jump")
        press_space()
        time.sleep(1)
        restart_game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the main function to run and give print "blip" and "jump", currently running all the other code and entirely skipping the main function.

[shows what the warning looks like in PyCharm - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYIB4.png)

Comment: by 'not running' at all, what does it output? Can you please add the output as well? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add `restart_game()` and `image_grab()` code as well?

Comment: @ParthS007 I added restart_game() & image_grab() code!

Comment: Also @VaibhavSharma , the program is not outputing anything for the main function. It is just running everything else. PyCharm says "This code is unreachable" when I hover over the section

Comment: Not clear how you are running this code

Comment: how do you mean? @cricket_007 I'm running it through PyCharm. I understand the code is unreachable, I'm just not sure how I can make the function run constantly

Comment: Does your code perhaps get stuck somewhere before it reaches the end of the file? you must trace the flow of the program to see where it actually will go. Pycharm is not infallible in determining if something is reachable or not, so don't take it as gospel. Using various print statements throughout your code to determine what's going on is a bit old-school, but still very effective. (think something like `print('starting main')` at the beginning of your  `main` function just to know it was actually called)

Comment: Does it work if you run the script from the command prompt instead of Pycharm?

Comment: @Aaron Just added the print statements. Everything runs except for the main function

Comment: @ForgeAhead could you send the screenshot from PyCharm? As I guess, your if __name__ code is not at the top-level

Comment: @Desiigner I added a screenshot to the post

Comment: @ForgeAhead your code is unreachable because you have an infinite loop before your main() function definition. Since code is written from the top to the bottom, it's frozen on your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unreachable because you have an infinite while loop before main() definition. It's a good practice in applications that require while loop to put it inside if **name** == '**main**' condition after all variables are declared.
Like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        do_something()
```